# Error enabling flyspell mode in Emacs

Tags: org-mode, init-file, flyspell, ispell, hunspell

I use `flyspell` `hunspell` for checking my spelling mistakes in Emacs. Recently, when I run `M-x flyspell-mode` in `.org` or `.tex` files I got the following error:

```
Error enabling Flyspell mode:
 (hunspell exited with signal  Abort trap: 6)
```

I didn't get this error in the past, and I think I have changed nothing from my config.

My `.emacs` file for `latex`, `ispell` and `hunspell` are:

```el
;; LATEX
;;
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)

(setq ispell-program-name "hunspell") ;; Dictionaries
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'visual-line-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'TeX-source-correlate-mode)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)

(setq TeX-output-view-style
    (quote
     (("^pdf$" "." "evince -f %o")
      ("^html?$" "." "iceweasel %o"))))

;;
;;ispell config
;;
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/local/bin"))
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/bin")))
```

How can I debug this?

## UPDATE

I solved the problem by:

1. upgrade brew
2. removing:

```el
(setq ispell-program-name "hunspell") ;; Dictionaries

;;
;;ispell config
;;
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/local/bin"))
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/bin")))
```

3. and adding:

```el
(setq ispell-program-name "hunspell")
(setq ispell-local-dictionary "en_GB")
(setq ispell-local-dictionary-alist
      '(("en_GB" "[[:alpha:]]" "[^[:alpha:]]" "[']" nil nil nil utf-8)))
```

Comment: There is some problem with the interface to hunspell version 1.7.  See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/47344/2710 for a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to specify the environment paths? Doesn't your `aspell` work when you type `aspell --version` in your terminal? In any case, this is my `flyspell` configuration:

```el
;; Spell-check
(require 'flyspell)
(setq flyspell-issue-message-flag nil
      ispell-local-dictionary "en_GB"
      ispell-program-name "aspell"
      ispell-extra-args '("--sug-mode=ultra"))

(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'flyspell-prog-mode)
```

Sorry, didn't realise you were using `hunspell`. I think `aspell` is the preferred utility. You have to install `aspell` separately from your terminal and install the required dictionary as well.

Comment: I am not sure but I think aspell is no longer maintained. Anyway I have already solved my issue. Thanks.